# How to pass special characters through php from a mssql database

Tags: php, android, sql-server, json

I have this code is working fine my application gets the data with json and is all fine but when I insert special characters like `ñ` which I need to get I can't have been told that I should use the `utf8_encode` but I just don't know how to apply it here since.

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectionInfo.php');


    //Set up our connection
    $connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    $connectionInfo->GetConnection();

    if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
    {
        //Connection failed
        echo 'No Connection';
    }

    else
    {
        if (isset($_POST['mod']) && isset($_POST['lec']) && isset($_POST['clase']))
        {   
        $mod = $_POST['mod'];
        $lec = $_POST['lec'];
        $clase = $_POST['clase'];
        //Create query to retrieve all contacts
        $query = 'SELECT TituloEjercicio,PreguntaEjercicio,Opcion1Ejercicio,Opcion2Ejercicio,Opcion3Ejercicio,Opcion4Ejercicio,EstaCorrectaEjercicio FROM ejercicios WHERE QueModulo = ? and QueLeccion = ? and Queclase = ?';
        $params = array($mod,$lec,$clase);      
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query,$params);

        if (!$stmt)
        {
            //Query failed
            echo 'Query failed';
        }
        else
        {
            $contacts = array(); //Create an array to hold all of the contacts
            //Query successful, begin putting each contact into an array of contacts

            while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) //While there are still contacts
            {
                //Create an associative array to hold the current contact
                //the names must match exactly the property names in the contact class in our C# code.
                $contact = array("lbl_variable_cuestionario_titulo" => $row['TituloEjercicio'],
                                 "lbl_variable_pregunta" => $row['PreguntaEjercicio'],
                                 "opcion1" => $row['Opcion1Ejercicio'],
                                 "opcion2" => $row['Opcion2Ejercicio'],
                                 "opcion3" => $row['Opcion3Ejercicio'],
                                 "opcion4" => $row['Opcion4Ejercicio'],
                                 "EstaCorrecta" => $row['EstaCorrectaEjercicio']
                                 );                                          
                //Add the contact to the contacts array
                array_push($contacts, $contact);
            }

            //Echo out the contacts array in JSON format
            echo json_encode($contacts);
            sqlsrv_close($connectionInfo->conn);
        }
        }
        sqlsrv_close($connectionInfo->conn);
    }
    sqlsrv_close($connectionInfo->conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue lies with pushing non-latin characters to MySQL then you might just have to configure your database to use UTF8. There are good [tutorials online](http://cameronyule.com/2008/07/configuring-mysql-to-use-utf-8/) that show you how to do that.

Comment: Im using mssql no mysql any way to do it there?

Comment: MSSQL does not support UTF8 as far as my Google-fu goes. There do seem to be ways to work around that though. [See what you can find out.](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=configuring%20mssql%20utf8)